# Regex: replace text with part of the file full path in SublimeText 3

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

In a "main directory" I have a lot of .txt files, in a lot of subdirectories.
Something like

"C:\FirstDir\SecondDir\ **MainDir\SomeSubDir_specific_subdirs_\** *.txt"

In each file I want to replace the line:

```
 reference = someotherfile.ext
```

with

```
 reference = MainDir\SomeSubDir\_specific_subdirs_\someotherfile.ext
```

I've built this expressions:

```
find:    (reference = )(?!_this_dir_)(.*\.txt)
replace: \1MainDir\\SomeSubDir\\_this_dir_\\\2
```

but it requires me to open one folder at time and write the folder name "_this_dir_" each time.

There's a way to have (as an internal variable of SublimeText, or from some regex trick) the file directory so i can automate the whole process?
(_specific_subdirs_ is the directory of the file i'm editing)

Comment: That is not a job for an editor. Write a script in your favorite scripting language.