# How to recursively edit a lot of files adding part of their own path to some line?

Tags: regex, replace

On a Win7 PC i have a deep but recursive directory structure

```
    Drive
      |
      +--a_Dir/.../MainDir
                     |
                     +--MainSubDir
                     |      |
                     |      +--George
                     |      |      |
                     |      |      +--AFile.edt
                     |      |      |
                     |      |      +--AnotherFile.edt
                     |      |      |
                     |      |      +--...
                     |      |      
                     |      +--Mildred
                     |      |      |
                     |      |      +--... .edt
                     |      |      
                     |      +--OtherPeople....
                     |             |
                     |             +--... .edt
                     |
                     |
                     +--ReferenceSubDir
                            |      
                            +--George
                            |      |
                            |      +--ARefFile.ref
                            |      |
                            |      +--AnotherRefFile.ref
                            |      |
                            |      +--...
                            |      
                            +--Mildred
                            |      |
                            |      +--... .ref
                            |      
                            +--OtherPeople....
                                   |
                                   +--... .ref
```

A .edt file **MAY** contain one or more lines like this:
`reference = SomeReferenceFile.ref`

I need to change that lines adding the appropriate path after the "=" sign.

As example, suppose that the file *George/AFile.edt* contains

`reference = ARefFile.ref`

I need to change it like this:

`reference = MainDir/ReferenceSubDir/George/ARefFile.ref`

So, i need to find all the .edt which contains "reference = ", know the directory containing each of the found files, and edit each line in that way.

I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895118/regex-replace-text-with-part-of-the-file-full-path-in-sublimetext-3) with the search/replace functionality in SublimeText3 but i don't have (found) a variable containing the path i could use for "mass" replacing.

I don't care what to use (batch files, free utilities) as this will be the only time i'll do this job,

Thanks

Comment: how many files?

Comment: @jhnc: something less than 2000 files, scattered in about 150 "people" folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with a powershell script.

Here it is, in case someone else find it useful:

```
$include = @("*.edt")
$FolderToSearch = "x:\a_Dir\aSubDir\MainDir\MainSubDir\" 
$FindExpr = "(Reference = )(?!ReferenceSubDir\\)(.*\.ref)"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderToSearch -Recurse -Include $include 

$opts = @()
$opts += "IgnoreCase"
$regex = new-object Text.RegularExpressions.Regex $FindExpr, $opts

foreach ($file in $files){
    if (Select-String -Quiet $file -Pattern $FindExpr ) {
        $Percorso = Split-Path -Path $file
        $ReplaceExpr = $Percorso.Replace($FolderToSearch,'$1ReferenceSubDir\') + '\$2'
        Write-Host $ReplaceExpr
        try {
            $text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName)
        }
        catch [Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {
            write-error $ERROR[0]
            continue
        }

        $replace = $regex.Replace($text, $ReplaceExpr)

        try {
            [IO.File]::WriteAllText($file, $replace)
        }
        catch [Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {
            write-error $ERROR[0]
            continue
        }
    }
}
```